# Cannot use Version 2 docker-compose files on Vagrant

Tags: linux, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I am having a baffling problem.

I cannot use docker-compose version 2 files on a vagrant guest. (If it matters the host is 15.10 ubuntu).

I am getting the following error: 
*The Docker Engine is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater*

The Vagrantfile I am using is the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
# SET THE IP ADDRESS AND BRIDGE SELECTION TO MATCH YOUR NETWORK
#

unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-docker-compose")
  system("vagrant plugin install vagrant-docker-compose")
  system("vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest")
  puts "Dependencies installed, please try the command again."
  exit
end
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder "./web", "/var/www", create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "./provision/setup.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline:
     "ps aux | grep 'sshd:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"
  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
  # Assign a name to your host VM
  config.vm.hostname = "docker"
  # Use the phusion ubuntu box for our host VM
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
  # Run scripts to place web, docker and repo files
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "./provision/public_gitrepos_to_vagrant_dir.sh"

  # Forward port 8080 to host machine
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8081
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8082
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host:8000
  #network
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.60"

  # Sync your project in the /vagrant directory inside the VM
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose, yml: "/vagrant/docker/docker-compose.yml", rebuild: true, run: "always"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "./provision/dockerstart.sh"
  end
```

Docker-compose works fine with V1 version YAML files, but gives me the warning and fails with V2.  V2 works fine on the host machine, it is only on Vagrant that I have this issue.

How can I get a V2 docker-compose files to work with Vagrant? Am I just missing something or it is a bigger issue?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

#### Old Docker Version

The Docker installation running on that Vagrant VM is old and out of date. Per the error you're seeing, it is older than the minimum `1.10.0` required for v2 of Docker Compose.

> I am getting the following error: The Docker Engine is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater

Here is the source of the boxes you downloaded:

https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/vagrant/boxes/

Right off the [Phusion page](https://github.com/phusion/open-vagrant-boxes) there is a link to the above via "Prebuilt boxes". You can see from the dates they were last updated in **May 2014**, which is forever in Docker-time.

Per the Docker Compose documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-2

> Version 2 files are supported by Compose 1.6.0+ and require a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0+.

### Solutions

#### Native Docker on Ubuntu Host

As you are running Ubuntu on your host, you can run native Docker directly. It will be faster and much simpler to work with than in a VM.

Install on Ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

#### Vagrant Docker Provider

If your requirements are to run in Vagrant, you can use manage it using Vagrant's built-in Docker provider, with no VM/VBox:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/boxes.html

> The Docker provider does not require a Vagrant box. The config.vm.box setting is completely optional.

Note: You will need Docker installed on your Ubuntu host for this.